# Ошибка при завершении работы машины состояний python aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

В завершении создания карточки выдается ошибка (ниже под кодом). В чем может быть проблема?

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import StatesGroup, State
from aiogram.types.base import String
from aiogram.utils import executor
from aiogram.contrib.middlewares.logging import LoggingMiddleware
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters import Text  # Import Text filter
from aiogram.types import ParseMode
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
import asyncio
import logging
from database import createCard, db_start

from config import API_TOKEN  # Импортируем токен из файла config.py


# Запуск бд при запуске бота
async def on_startup(_):
    await db_start()


# Инициализация бота
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=MemoryStorage())
dp.middleware.setup(LoggingMiddleware())


class CardStorage(StatesGroup):
    name = State()
    discription = State()



@dp.message_handler(commands=['create'])
async def CardCreate(message: types.Message) -> None:
    await message.reply("Давай создадим твою карточку! Как бы ты хотел(a), чтобы тебя звали?")
    await CardStorage.name.set()  # Машина состояния на имя (ожидание)


@dp.message_handler(state=CardStorage.name)
async def LoadName(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext) -> None:
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['name'] = message.text

    await message.reply('Теперь расскажи о себе!')
    await CardStorage.next()


@dp.message_handler(state=CardStorage.discription)
async def LoadDiscription(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext) -> None:
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['discription'] = message.text
        print(data)

    await message.reply('Карточка создана!')
    await state.finish()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True, on_startup=on_startup)
```

```
ERROR:asyncio:Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-21' coro=<Dispatcher._process_polling_updates() done, defined at C:\Users\harla\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py:409> exception=KeyError(-1001458232515)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\harla\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 417, in _process_polling_updates
    for responses in itertools.chain.from_iterable(await self.process_updates(updates, fast)):
  File "C:\Users\harla\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 238, in process_updates
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
  File "C:\Users\harla\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 116, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "C:\Users\harla\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 259, in process_update
    return await self.message_handlers.notify(update.message)
  File "C:\Users\harla\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 116, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "C:\wiedzminPolitical\main.py", line 58, in LoadDiscription
    await state.finish()
  File "C:\Users\harla\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\storage.py", line 322, in finish
    await self.storage.finish(chat=self.chat, user=self.user)
  File "C:\Users\harla\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\storage.py", line 202, in finish
    await self.reset_state(chat=chat, user=user, with_data=True)
  File "C:\Users\harla\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\contrib\fsm_storage\memory.py", line 78, in reset_state
    self._cleanup(chat, user)
  File "C:\Users\harla\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\contrib\fsm_storage\memory.py", line 108, in _cleanup
    if self.data[chat][user] == {'state': None, 'data': {}, 'bucket': {}}:
KeyError: -1001458232515
```